# mongodb to display only str of objectId

Tags: mongodb

collection A document 1

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c2ee03224acf45a663d8f09"),
    "_class" : "document.domain.DDD",
    "generated" : false,
    "linkIds" : [],
    "types" : [],
    "metadata" : {       
        "templateId" : "ABDC",
        "userId" : "Master"
    }
    "versions" : [ 
        {
            "revision" : "fb4fb8ec-edfe-4a3e-a1a9-c8c4b2bce678",
            "fileId" : "5c2ee03224acf45a663d8f08"
        }
    ]
}

collection B document 1

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c2ee03224acf45a663d8f08"),
    "_class" : "document.domain.RDF",
    "extension" : ".pdf",
    "rootPath" : "D"
    "size" : 152754
 }
```

the field id in collection A , document 1 appears as String in objectid of collection B doc 1.

how to lookup for the string in collection B which appears as objecid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use mongodb aggregation there
you have view this more on 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/
and you have to use $lookup operator more you learn this on 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

you can achived your task doing this

```
  collectionA.aggregate.([
    {
    $match:{},// To match  and get all doc
    },
    {
       $lookup:
         {
           from: collection B//<collection to join>,
           localField: versions.fileId//<field from the input documents>,
           foreignField: _id//<field from the documents of the "from" collection>,
           as: versions.file//<output array field>
         }
    }])
```

Comment: Will the _id field automatically accept the string and convert it to object Id?

Comment: Yes you have write  _id